# Virtual function not working

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

The first class is:

```
class SistemPornire{
protected:
    Motor &_motor;
    Electromotor &_electromotor;

public:
    SistemPornire(Motor&,Electromotor&);
    virtual void pornire_motor();
    void opreste_motor();
};
```

The implementation of the virtual function is:

```
SistemPornire::SistemPornire(Motor &motor, Electromotor &electromotor)
    :_motor(motor), _electromotor(electromotor)
{
}

void SistemPornire::pornire_motor()
{
     std::cout << "Sistemul de pornire a trimis comanda porneste_motor electromotorului." << std::endl;
    this->_electromotor.start(_motor);
}
```

The second class:

```
class SistemPornireCuPreincalzire:public SistemPornire {
public:
    SistemPornireCuPreincalzire(Motor&,Electromotor&);
    void pornire_motor();
};
```

Its implementation:

```
SistemPornireCuPreincalzire::SistemPornireCuPreincalzire(Motor&motor, Electromotor&electromotor)
    : SistemPornire(motor, electromotor)
{

}

void SistemPornireCuPreincalzire::pornire_motor()
{
    std::cout << "A inceput preincalzirea" <<std::endl<< "Preincalzirea incheiata" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Sistemul de pornire a trimis comanda porneste_motor electromotorului." << std::endl;
    this->_electromotor.start(_motor);
}
```

In the main function I'm trying to call the function `pornire_motor()` for an object of type `SistemPornireCuPreincalzire` yet it would print out the message from the `SistemPornire::pornire_motor()` function.

Could you please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? Is the information I have provided sufficient?

```
class Autoturism {

private:
    Electromotor electromotor;
    Motor motor;
    SistemPornire sistem_pornire;
    SistemDirectie sistem_directie;
    CutieViteze cutieviteze;

public:
    Autoturism(SistemPornire&, Electromotor&, Motor&, SistemDirectie&);
    void porneste_autoturism();
    void condu_la_destinatie();
    void parcheaza_autoturism();
};

Autoturism::Autoturism(SistemPornire &sp, Electromotor&e, Motor&m, SistemDirectie&sd): sistem_pornire(sp), electromotor(e), motor(m), sistem_directie(sd)
{

}

void Autoturism::porneste_autoturism()
{
    std::cout <<  "Comanda porneste_autoturism a fost trimisa catre sistemul de pornire." << std::endl;
    this->sistem_pornire.pornire_motor();
}

void Autoturism::condu_la_destinatie()
{
    this->porneste_autoturism();
    std::cout << "Odata ce masina a pornit, soferul o poate conduce la destinatie." << std::endl;

    this->cutieviteze.gearUp();
    this->sistem_directie.stanga(0);
    this->cutieviteze.gearUp();
    this->cutieviteze.gearUp();
    this->cutieviteze.gearDown();
    this->sistem_directie.stanga(90);
    this->cutieviteze.gearUp();
    this->sistem_directie.stanga(0);
    this->cutieviteze.gearDown();
    this->sistem_directie.dreapta(30);
    this->sistem_directie.dreapta(0);
    this->sistem_directie.dreapta(10);


    std::cout << "Odata ce s-a ajuns la destinatie masina e gata de a fi parcata." << std::endl;
    this->parcheaza_autoturism();
    std::cout << "Soferul a ajuns la destinatie." << std::endl;
}

void Autoturism::parcheaza_autoturism()
{
    std::cout <<  "Comanda parcheaza_autoturism a fost trimisa catre sistemul de pornire." << std::endl;
    this->sistem_pornire.opreste_motor();
}
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
    Motor motor;
    Electromotor electromotor;
    SistemPornire sistempornire(motor, electromotor);
    SistemDirectie sistemdirectie;
    SistemPornireCuPreincalzire sistempornireINC(motor, electromotor);

    Autoturism masina(sistempornireINC, electromotor, motor,sistemdirectie);

    std::cout << "Porneste autoturism:" << std::endl;
    masina.porneste_autoturism();

    std::cout << "Parcheaza autoturism:" << std::endl;
    masina.parcheaza_autoturism();

    std::cout << "Condu la destinatie:" << std::endl;
    masina.condu_la_destinatie();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing object slicing. Can't be sure without the calling code.

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Show the main function.

Comment: Can you show us how you declare the object and call the `pornire_motor()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at some parts of your code and analyze what is going on. This is your code from `main`:

```
Motor motor;
Electromotor electromotor;
SistemPornire sistempornire(motor, electromotor);
SistemDirectie sistemdirectie;
SistemPornireCuPreincalzire sistempornireINC(motor, electromotor);
```

Notice how you create an instance of `SistemPornireCuPreincalzire` here which you then pass into the constructor of `Autoturism`:

```
Autoturism masina(sistempornireINC, electromotor, motor,sistemdirectie);
```

Let's look at the constructor of `Autoturism` for a second, shall we?

```
Autoturism(SistemPornire&, Electromotor&, Motor&, SistemDirectie&);
```

Hmm, it takes a *reference* to a `SistemPornire` and we're passing a reference to `SistemPornireCuPreincalzire`. That's not necessarily an error, but it's enough to get you thinking.  So let's look at what the `Autoturism` constructor does:

```
Autoturism::Autoturism(SistemPornire &sp, Electromotor&e, 
                       Motor&m, SistemDirectie&sd)
    : sistem_pornire(sp), electromotor(e), motor(m), sistem_directie(sd)
{

}
```

Hmm... what's the type of `sistem_pornire`? Looking at the code, we see it's declared as:

```
SistemPornire sistem_pornire;
```

Just seeing this is enough to explain *why* virtual functions aren't working. The type of `sistem_pornire` is known at compile-time and there's no virtual dispatch. Remember, virtual functions happen only when you call a virtual function through a *pointer* (i.e. you *must* use the `->` operator).

But let's dig a bit deeper too...

So the constructor takes a reference to a `SistemPornire` instance and uses it to initialize the instance of the `sistem_pornire` member in `Autoturism`. In other words, you copy-construct the `sistem_pornire` object with the `SistemPornire` part of the `SistemPornireCuPreincalzire` you declare in `main`.

The object from `main` is never called and never used.

You should read carefully about the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) and about [virtual functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-functions.html) dispatch in C++.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

*edit*

In the updated question, as @Roddy points out, slicing occurs in the `Autoturism` constructor.

You are slicing your objects by assigning a derived object to a base object.

```
SistemPornireCuPreincalzire derived = SistemPornireCuPreincalzire();

SistemPornire base = derived; // sliced
```

You need to refer to the derived class by reference:

```
SistemPornireCuPreincalzire derived = SistemPornireCuPreincalzire();

SistemPornire& base = derived; // no slicing
```

See:

- [What is the slicing problem in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1084416).
- [Why is 'object slice' needed in C++ ? Why it is allowed ? For more bugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7516545/1084416).

Comment: The slicing happens in the AutoTurism constructor

Comment: There's slicing, but that's *not* the issue here.

Comment: @NikBougalis Why is slicing not the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type the *only* issue. Even if you eliminate the slicing, there's no virtual dispatch because no calls are via pointers.