# C++: Is there a way to merge lists of various variable types into one?

Tags: c++, stdlist

Here's the desired function written in Kotlin:

```
    // these 3 classes inherit from MenuItem class
    val subOptions: MutableList<MenuOption> = mutableListOf(),
    val entries: List<MenuEntry> = emptyList(),
    val actions: List<MenuAction> = emptyList() 

    fun getOrderedMenuItems(): List<MenuItem> = entries.plus(actions).plus(subOptions)
```

Is there any way to go around this problem using std::list, or some different type of container? If not, how else could it be translated? Any hints will be highly appreciated.

**@edit**

Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. Basically, I wanted to connect those lists into one list. I tried to use splice() and merge() as such:

```cpp
list<MenuItem> mergedList = list<MenuItem>();
mergedList.splice(mergedList.end(), actions);
```

And I got this:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::splice [with _Tp=MenuItem, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::_List_iterator, std::__cxx11::list<MenuAction, std::allocator>) -- object type is: std::__cxx11::list<MenuItem, std::allocator>

Here's what did the trick for me:

```cpp
list<MenuItem> MenuOption::getOrderedMenuItems() {
    list<MenuItem> mergedList = list<MenuItem>();
    for(MenuItem const& i : actions) {
        mergedList.push_back(i);
    }
    for(MenuItem const& i : subOptions) {
        mergedList.push_back(i);
    }
    for(MenuItem const& i : entries) {
        mergedList.push_back(i);
    }
    return mergedList;
}
```

Comment: Have you search in the documentation ? [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)

Comment: Asking for direct code translations is generally not allowed. Please show the attempt you've made at writing this in c++.

Comment: Please read, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280538/how-to-verify-if-a-void-pointer-void-is-one-of-two-data-types/58281061#58281061 I am tempted to identify it as a duplicate, because of what i suspect you are considering.

Comment: @Yunnosch Please don't suggest that :) There is no evidence in the post that the OP knows any c++ at all, and they might actually try that even if it's unnecessary.

Comment: You could probably use `std::any` and `std::merge`

Comment: @thibsc `std::merge` is meant to merge 2 *sorted* ranges

Comment: @cigien Hmm. My point is that using void pointers requires MORE knowledge on what is actually pointed to, as the answers there explain. Your comment seems to indicate that you read something else there, but I cannot imagine how you did that.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, I was thinking about it from OP's point of view. They click on the link, see `void*`, don't fully understand the answer, and after a bit of googling, find that they could maybe use `void*` for their problem, and waste time writing bad code :p Just wanted OP to avoid that :)

Comment: Read this [Object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: @cigien Shudder. you seem to have an even more pessimistic opinion than me, of new StackOverflow users when September is coming in. And I fail to see an error in your thinking. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use vectors (or lists, but that's an inferior option) of *pointers* (smart or otherwise; smart pointers should be preferred but I don't show them for brevity).

```
std::vector<MenuItem*> out;
// these 3 classes inherit from MenuItem class
std::vector<MenuOption*> subOptions;
std::vector<MenuEntry*> entries;
std::vector<MenuAction*> actions;

out.insert(out.end(), entries.begin(), entries.end());
out.insert(out.end(), actions.begin(), actions.end());
out.insert(out.end(), subOptions.begin(), suboptions.end());
```

You then can `std::sort` the `out` vector if you need a sorted vector. It is also possible to use `std::merge` if your original vectors are sorted to begin with. You probably will need to pass a custom comparator to either function, otherwise they will compare pointers, which is probably not what you want.

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188221/why-cant-i-do-polymorphism-with-normal-variables) for more information.

Comment: Where did OP mention that they are working with (or intending to work with) sorted ranges? `std::merge` seems irrelevant for this question

Comment: @Ayxan the original function is called `getOrderedMenuItems`. I don't know what kind of order is meant by that so I explain how to get sorted output, just in case.